# How to merge nested attributes in permit + Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

```
params.require(:task).permit(:summary, comments_attributes: [:id, :content])
```

I want to add **user_id** and **project_id** in comments_attributes.

```
user_id    = current_user.id
project_id = project.id
```

I tried with below but not working

```
params.require(:task).permit(:summary, comments_attributes: [:id, :content]).merge(user_id: current_user.id, comments_attributes: [user_id: current_user.id, project_id: project.id])
```

Please help me how can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Although an old question, the right answer IMHO is this ->

In Rails 5, instead of `.to_h.deep_merge` you should use [reverse_merge](https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/reverse_merge)

```
params.require(:task).permit(:summary, comments_attributes: [:id, :content]).reverse_merge(user_id: current_user.id, comments_attributes: [user_id: current_user.id, project_id: project.id])
```

Answer (score 1):

you will have to use [deep_merge](http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/deep_merge)

```
params.require(:task).permit(:summary, comments_attributes: [:id, :content]).deep_merge(user_id: current_user.id, comments_attributes: [user_id: current_user.id, project_id: project.id])
```

Comment: How does this work in Rails 5? It seems that `deep_merge` is no longer a subclass of `ActionController::Parameters`. I am getting an `undefined method` error for `deep_merge` in Rails 5.

Comment: @Tintin81 check the new answer. All the best

Comment: @Tintin81 try to use `reverse_merge`

Answer (score 1):

Convert permitted params to hash first, and then deep merge the hash:

```
params.require(:task).permit(
    :summary,
    comments_attributes: [
        :id,
        :content
    ]
).to_h.deep_merge(
    user_id: current_user.id,
    comments_attributes: [
        user_id: current_user.id,
        project_id: project.id
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I could not get the [current top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40981383/14895) to work. `reverse_merge` on its own does not appear to iteratively call `reverse_merge` down to the nested `comments_attributes` version of `ActionController::Parameters`. Rather, I needed to do something like this:

```
_params = params.require(:task).permit(:summary, comments_attributes: [:id, :content])
_params.reverse_merge!(user_id: current_user.id)
_params[:comments_attributes].each do |key, value|
  _params[:comments_attributes][key] = value.reverse_merge(user_id: current_user.id, project_id: project.id)
end
_params
```

Happy to hear if there is an more straightforward answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
 params[:task][:comments_attributes].merge!({user_id: current_user.id, project_id: project.id})
```