# Why am I getting an undefined method `deep_merge' for ActionController::Parameters error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actioncontroller

In my Rails 5 app I am trying to do this in a controller:

```
  def create
    company_params = params.require(:company).permit(
      :name,
      :email,
      :people_attributes => [
        :first_name,
        :last_name
      ]
    ).deep_merge(
      :creator_id => current_user.id,
      :people_attributes => [
        :creator_id => current_user.id
      ]
    )
    @company = current_account.companies.build(company_params)
    if @company.save
      flash[:success] = "Company created."
      redirect_to companies_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

For some reason I am getting this error, though:

> undefined method `deep_merge' for  ActionController::Parameters:0x007fa24c39cfb0

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I couldn't get `deep_merge` to work, so I ended up doing this:

```
  def create
    company_params = params.require(:company).permit(
      :name, 
      :email,
      :people_attributes => [
        :first_name,
        :last_name
      ]
    )
    @company = current_account.companies.build(company_params)
    @company.creator = current_user
    @person = @company.people.last
    @person.account = current_account
    @person.creator = current_user
    if @company.save
      flash[:success] = "Company created."
      redirect_to companies_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

Not sure if this is good or bad practice. Feedback appreciated!

Comment: It's passable. Not the most beatiful ruby code out there, but it works and that's what matters :)

Answer (score 4):

> What am I missing here?

That `params` is an instance of `ActionController::Parameters`. It is not a Hash. It has *some* merge methods, though.

```
params.methods.grep(/merge/)
=> [:reverse_merge!, :reverse_merge, :merge!, :merge]
```

If you want `deep_merge`, convert your params to a hash in some way.

Comment: OK, thanks! Then [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40981206/how-to-merge-nested-attributes-in-permit-rails?rq=1) is wrong. Basically, what I want is merge the `creator_id` into the `people_attributes`. Is there an alternative to using `deep_merge`?

Comment: @Tintin81: it's wrong now. Maybe two years ago ActionController::Parameters _was_ a subclass of Hash.

Comment: @Tintin81: "Is there an alternative to using deep_merge" - deep_merge looks like an appropriate tool here. Just make sure you operate on a hash. `params.require(:foo).permit(:bar).as_json.deep_merge(...)` or something like that.

Comment: Can't get this to work unfortunately. The `first_name` and `last_name` attributes do not get saved when using `.as_json.deep_merge`.

Answer (score 0):

Even though modifying params in the request cycle is not a good practice, but if you want to do that, there's always a `.to_hash.deep_merge` option for you to retrieve the hash back from params instance.

Comment: "modifying params in the request cycle is not a good practice" - what are you talking about? That's the entire _raison d'être_ of strong params.

Comment: `permit` returns a new hash with those keys in it, so you're not modifying the real params variable. I think you misunderstood the definition of `modify` here and `whitelisting` technique used in strong parameter.

Comment: There is an old article about this : )

https://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/2013/09/18/don-t-modify-the-params-hash/

Comment: Hah, or maybe it is you who misunderstood something :) `deep_merge` also returns a new hash, leaving the original structure intact.

Comment: Thanks but when I use `.to_hash.deep_merge` the `first_name` and `last_name` attributes do not get saved. I don't know why that is.

Comment: @Tintin81: "I don't know why that is" - lack of attention on your part. Look closer, you don't have a hash there (in deep_merge)

Comment: @Tintin81: you see it?

Comment: @Tintin81: you pass array to `people_attributes` in deep_merge. Should be a hash.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: OK, thanks. I already tried that a while ago. The problem is that it results in a `TypeError`: `no implicit conversion of String into Integer` when I try to create my `company`. It's really tricky to get the syntax right here...